# How to get the nodes from root to the leaf?

Tags: javascript, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, preorder

Suppose I have an array A = [10, 30, 25, 9, 3, 7, 15, 1] in preorder traversal. I am not understanding how I can find all the nodes from a leaf to the root. Suppose, I need to find out all the nodes from 7 to the 10. Can someone help me to find this in JavaScript?

Comment: Do you know how to reconstruct the binary tree from the traversal result? Can you *draw* it?

Comment: You tagged this with [tag:binary-search-tree], but the preorder traversal you provided cannot be about a binary search tree, since a preorder traversal always starts with the root, followed by the left child (if any). But 30 cannot be the left child, and so that means all further nodes are part of the right subtree, but then in a BST none of the remaining values can be less than 10, but yet there are such values. Please explain what this is about.